# Random javax.net.ssl.SSLExceptions using OkHttp client

Tags: java, android, ssl, okhttp

In my android app am using a okhttp client which trusts all ssl certificates. The problem is, am facing random SSLExceptions. For example 8 out of 10 calls fail due to SSLExceptions and 2 succeed.

Any pointers on why this might be happening?
Please let me know if you need more info.

stack trace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:273)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:230)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:201)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:81)
        at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This is how i create the okHttp client:

```
private OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();


        return createOkHttpClientWithTimeout(sslSocketFactory);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

protected OkHttpClient createOkHttpClientWithTimeout(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return okHttpClient;
}
```

Note: I know that trusting all SSL certificates is bad.